# Access Svelte Store from Middleware & Front End

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-store

I would like to access my Svelte store from my Middleware, because I want to save a value to the store when a certain process.on('message') value is observed.

I have tried, however, when I set up the store it starts out with the initial value and this can be seen in my front end AND in the middleware subscriber, so they appear to be the same store. But when I update the store from the front end (using .update or .set), it updates, but never triggers an update at the back end subscriber.

And vice-versa, I can update it from the back end (with action from process.on('message')) and it will change its store value, but will not trigger any subscribers in the front end. It is simply two separate stores, with the same name. Does it make sense that this should happen? And is there any way to make this work as one store?

Thanks so much for any insight you can provide.

Comment: Middleware 'lives' server side, while your front end 'lives' in your user's browser, so there's a clear disconnect. The initial value is visible on both sides because the page is initially server-rendered, but beyond that both stores are disconnected. I'd suggest using websockets for this? Create a channel between the server and the client (or clients if it's a broadcast), emit a message when your `process.on()` event fires, and update the store on the client side when the message is received.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks! I understand. I will use websockets to talk between the server and browser. This is new territory for me so I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The stores are running separate instance at client and server. You could make two separate stores for client and server in the files to make things easier.